# retrofit invoking asynchronous call synchronously

Tags: java, android, retrofit, synchronous

This looks weird but I ended up in this situation. Implemented Restful API call using Retrofit asynchronously. Now there is a sudden requirement change and have to call API one after the other (One at a time), so that in the second API call I have to send session token received from the previous response. One way is to make every API call as synchronous but it takes time to implement this change.

I have tried :

1. Used `setExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),new
   MainThreadExecutor)`  for `RestAdapter.Builder`.This didn't work
   since API calls are asynchronous and before getting response for the
   previous API call second call is made. So the second request has
   invalid session token.
2. In the class where I have implemented all Restful Web services,
   used  `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` , this also didn't work
   for the same reason.

   Could anybody suggest how to resolve this with minimal changes.
   Webservice Manager is as below, this is partial and there are many more api's like login:

```
public class WebServiceManager {
    private static final String ROOT_PATH = Urls.REST_ROOT_URL;
    RestAdapter restAdapter;
    WebServiceInterface webServiceInterface;
    private String requestKey;
    private String sessionId;
    private Context context;

    public WebServiceManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        initializeWebServiceAdapter();
    }

    private void initializeWebServiceAdapter() {
        restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(ROOT_PATH)
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .build();
        webServiceInterface = restAdapter.create(WebServiceInterface.class);
    }

    private void setHeaderValues(BaseModel model) {
     SessionManager sm=  context.getApplicationContext().getSessionManager();
        model.getRequestHeader().setRequestKey(sm.getRequestKey());
        model.getRequestHeader().setSessionId(sm.getSessionId());
    }

    public void login(String emailID, String passwd, final WebServiceCallback loginModelWebServiceCallback) {
        LoginModel model = RestRequest.getLoginModel(emailID, passwd);
        setHeaderValues(model);
            webServiceInterface.login(model, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void success(LoginModel loginModel, Response response) {
                    if (loginModelWebServiceCallback != null)
                    {
                        SessionManager sm=  context.getApplicationContext().getSessionManager();
                        sm.setSessionDetails(response.getRequestKey(),response.getSessionId());
                        loginModelWebServiceCallback.success(loginModel);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    if (loginModelWebServiceCallback != null)
                        loginModelWebServiceCallback.failure(error);
                }
            });
        } 

}
```

Comment: You are calling two API's right?

Comment: So, call the second API after getting response from first API.

Comment: Yes there many more method the cited code is partial

Comment: Call the second API after getting response from first API.

Comment: But to do that I have to do lot of changes & need to maintain some queue, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think so, because you need to call only two API's na, so at first call the API to get session key and then login,.

Comment: @Nigam Patro I have updated question and there are many more APIs like login.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98302/discussion-between-nigam-patro-and-raviprakash).

Comment: Every time do you need to call API for session key?

Answer (score 0):

The Executor doesn't matter since you're always invoking the Retrofit service with the Callback argument, which makes it asynchronous.  If you want your Retrofit call to be synchronous then the service call method needs a return type, not void.  You can read this in the docs.

Once you make your API calls synchronous and ordered how you want, you can wrap them in a Runnable and let an Executor handle the threading for you.

Comment: Is this is the only solution? In this case I need to do lot of code refactoring, so looking for alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

A request can be made in the response from first API itself, when some parameter is expected for the second api call. Have a look at the sample :

```
public void login(String emailID, String passwd, final WebServiceCallback loginModelWebServiceCallback) {
    LoginModel model = RestRequest.getLoginModel(emailID, passwd);
    setHeaderValues(model);
    webServiceInterface.login(model, new Callback() {
      @Override
      public void success(LoginModel loginModel, Response response) {
        if (loginModelWebServiceCallback != null) {
          makeSecondAPIcall();
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        if (loginModelWebServiceCallback != null)
          loginModelWebServiceCallback.failure(error);
      }
    });
  }
```